# if function does not work in Excel.Can't see the issue

Tags: excel

So for school i'm working with this huge excel Dataset. I'm trying Excel 365 to find the word terrorist and return the value 1 with the follow code:

```
=IF'(A22="terrorist", "No", "Yes")
```

But I keep getting the excel error.

> There is a problem with the function
>
> - you type `=1+1`, cell shows: `2`
>
> to get around this type an apostrophe (') first:
>
> - you type `'=1+1` cell shows `=1+1`

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Drop the **single quote** after the *IF*

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'` - use simply:

```
=IF(A22="terrorist", 1, 0)
```

This will show 1 if A22 = "terrorist", otherwise it will show 0.

Comment: Still get the error with the above code. Is it because my file tpye is .csv?

Comment: I didn't read an error message? Tell us exactly what the error message says, please.

Comment: There's a problem with this formula.

Not trying to type a forumal?

When the first charcter is an equal(=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula.

you type: =1=1, cell shows : 2

To get around this, type an apostrphe (') firts:

you type: '=1=1, cell shows: =1+1

Comment: Do you use `,` or `;` to separate arguments in a formula?

Comment: =IF(A22="terrorist", 1, 0) well im using this formula, so should i replace the , into ; ?

Comment: Depending on your system locale settings, your list separator will be set to either `,` or `;`.

Comment: Where can i check this? When i use ; i get a different error.

Comment: No it's my first time using excel formula's, Well its quite an unclear error.
Since it only says #NAME?

Comment: Do some research into Excel basics, please.

Comment: Well i do know the excell basics, i just never used a formula, but now the problem arises that it only returns one value instead of returning a value for every cell